# keyboard event.code doesnt work in mobile (sveltekit)

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

how to handle keyboard input in mobile, especially "Space" key, because when i using event.key, event.keyCode, event.code, there's nothing work, the space doesn't work its like the event.code different, i have research how to handle keyboard but nothing work

```
 function handleKeyDown() {
        if (event.code === "Space") {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (game === "in progress") {
                nextWord();
            }
        }

        if (event.code === "Backspace") {
            event.preventDefault();
            checkPrevLetter();
        }

        if (game === "waiting for input") {
            startGame();
        }
}
```

```
function nextWord() {
        const isNotFirstLetter = letterIndex !== 0;
        const isOneLetterWord = words[wordIndex].length === 1;

        if (isNotFirstLetter || isOneLetterWord) {
            if (wordIndex < words.length) {
                const wordEl = wordsEl.children[wordIndex];
                const letterEls = wordEl.querySelectorAll(".letter");
                for (let i = letterIndex; i < letterEls.length; i++) {
                    letterEls[i].dataset.letter = "skipped";
                }
            }

            wordIndex += 1;
            letterIndex = 0;
            increaseScore();
            moveCaretToNextWord();
        }
    }
```

this is how i handle the keydown and go to the next word after press space, you can try it in type-masters.vercel.app on mobile, when on last letter and press space, its cant go to the next word not like in desktop version, thank you for the answer!

Comment: Maybe use the `input` event instead?

Comment: (You can read what was added from the event's [`data` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/data). Does not appear to catch pasting, so the `paste` event might need handling, too.)